# base class for stream classes

Tags: c++, stream, base-class

I have a test tomorrow and I came across a question, to which I can't find the answer. I would really appreciate if you could answer me my question.

What is the base class for most stream classes?

Thank you.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But you'll have to admit that the question is somewhat ambiguous as well.  "Most stream classes" is rather vague, and could mean many things.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes of course, I also stumbled over that when reading. But that doesn't really make this a good SO question, does it? If this would have been the particular point of the OP's confusion, they should have elaborated on it. IMHO such things can be fairly expected from a +100 rep user ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what they mean by "stream classes".  If they mean
the classes defined in `<iostream>`, `<istream>`, `<ostream>`,
`<fstream>` and `<sstream>` (but not those in `<streambuf>`),
then there are two "correct" answers: `std::ios_base` and
`std::basic_ios<>`.  The first is the base of the second, which
factors out the parts which are not dependent on the
instantiation type.  On the other hand, as a user, you should
probably think of the two as one common class, either
`std::basic_ios<char>` or `std::basic_ios<wchar_t>`, depending
on whether you are using narrow character streams or wide
character streams.